# how to pass variable from one function to another function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two functions in my controller like this.

```
function search_keyword()
{
    $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
    $this->data['result']    =   $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
    //print_r($this->data); 
    //$pro_id = [];
    foreach($this->data['result'] as $key => $val){
       $pro_id[] = $val->product_id;
    }
    print_r($pro_id);       
    $this->download_function();
    $this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
}
function download_function()
{
    //print_r($keyword);
    $this->data['re']    =   $this->csv->ExportCSV($keyword);
    $this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
}
```

I want to pass pro_id variable to download_function from search_keyword funtion.please help me to do this.

this is my model

```
function ExportCSV($pro_id)
{

    //print_r($keyword);
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $delimiter = ",";
    $newline = "\r\n";
    $filename = "filename_you_wish.csv";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id LIKE '%$pro_id%'";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($result, $delimiter, $newline);
    force_download($filename, $data);
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do this: `$this->download_function($pro_id);`

Comment: Pass variable  `$this->download_function(VARIABLE);` and getting using  `function download_function(VARIABLE)`

Comment: @saty I do what you said. function download_function($pro_id)
then I got an error which saying  Missing argument 1 for Search::download_function()  what should I do now?

Comment: @madforstrength I try that way. but then I got an error like this  Missing argument 1 for Search::download_function() .can you please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Post your model code!!!

Comment: yes I update my question.Sorry for commenting code in here.

Comment: Not in your comment .Edit your question and post your model code!!

Comment: The model script we need is `$this->mymodel->search($keyword);` thats the one we know is going wrong

Comment: And your function is not return anything!!

Comment: my function returns all data in may product table. but I looking for only one product detail.

Comment: Add the **search()** function from your model. **Thats what is being called just before** `foreach($this->data['result'] as $key => $val){` **and that is what we need to see**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite simple, do exactly what you would do to pass a paramter to any function.

```
public function search_keyword() {
    $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
    $this->data['result']    =   $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
    //print_r($this->data); 
    $pro_id = [];
    foreach($this->data['result'] as $key => $val){
       $pro_id[] = $val->product_id;
    }
    print_r($pro_id);       
    $this->download_function($pro_id);
    $this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
}

public function download_function($pro_ids) {
    //print_r($keyword);
    $this->data['re']      =   $this->csv->ExportCSV($keyword);
    $this->data['pro_ids'] =   $pro_ids;
    $this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
}
```

After some time in a chat room the solution we came up with was to chnage the code to this:

```
function search_keyword()
{
    $pro_id = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $this->download_function($pro_id);
    $this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
}

function download_function($pro_id)
{
    $this->data['re'] = $this->csv->ExportCSV($pro_id);
    $this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
}
```

Comment: yep. I tried this.but I got an error. also can you please tell my why you put a 's' after $pro_id in second function.

Comment: `$pro_ids` the `s` pluralises the name indicating there is likely to be more that one of whatever this is. It is an array afterall. **What error did you get**

Comment: Actually thinking about it, you said this was a controller. Should you not have a `public`/`protected`/`private` designator on the function definitions! See code change

Comment: I got error like this  Missing argument 1 for Search::download_function(). Please help me to solve this

Comment: Ahhhh I bet the database query is failing, or it is not returning what you think, and therefore the `foreach` is not running and therefore you are never actually creating the `$pro_id` variable. I uncommented the `//$pro_id = [];` try it now

Comment: you are exactly correct man..my database query also falling. I want to filter one product detail from my product table.but I gives me all product details.I have no idea whats going on.please help me to fix this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87984/discussion-between-udara-suranga-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 1):

```
function search_keyword()
{
    $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
    $this->data['result']    =   $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
    //print_r($this->data); 
    //$pro_id = [];
    foreach($this->data['result'] as $key => $val){
       $pro_id[] = $val->product_id;
    }
    print_r($pro_id);       
    $this->download_function($pro_id);
    $this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
}
function download_function($pro_id)
{
    //print_r($keyword);
    $this->data['re']    =   $this->csv->ExportCSV($keyword);
    $this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
}
```

You can pass it through parameter.

Comment: I try this. but then I got error like this  Missing argument 1 for Search::download_function(). what should I do now.

Comment: If you want to access the function download_function, you must mention the argument. Like this,
$pro_id=1;
http://localhost/diectory/controllername/download_function/$pro_id